# Adams Bashforth method question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider an ordinary differential equation

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = 0.5y - 2.5\sin(t),~~  0 <t \le 12$$

for the function $y(t)$ with the initial condition $y(0) = 2$

- Derive equations for Adams-Bashforth three-step method applied to this 
  problem. Provide an expression for the value of the approximate solution 
  $w_{i+1}$ at a timestep $t_{i+1}$ in terms of previously calculated values. Take 
  required starting values from the exact solution $y(t)= 2 \cos(t) + \sin(t)$. 
  Provide the starting values.
- Write a Matlab code implementing the method for this problem. Provide 
  the text of the code

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you done, can you please share? Regards

Comment: Looking at [the wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method), I think [the other question you posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467903/adams-moulton-ode) could be really combined into this question.

Comment: I really need help guys, I've tried to answer them. Anyone?

Comment: All my work is on paper at the moment and to type up would be very long. Plus I've probably made a lot of mistakes, hence why I want to see the answers that you guys will get

Comment: That was an accidental copy and paste. C'mon stop being so naggy... I'm simply asking for help

Comment: I've started to get the ball rolling, but if you want more, you have to meet us halfway and give us some more information. Where are you getting stuck? Does my answer, as written, make sense so far? Are you having trouble writing the code?

Comment: @user90425 Part of the reason why this is closed is that you have not shown your work (this has to do with an ongoing disagreement regarding the treatment of "problem statement questions" among users of this site).  If you want more useful answers, I suggest you try scanning and posting your notes or typing them out.  It's easy to upload images, and if you edit in the url, a person with sufficient reputation would be happy to edit your question to allow the images to display.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for the A-B 3-step method, as seen in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method#Adams.E2.80.93Bashforth_methods), can be defined iteratively as follows:
$$
y_{n+3} = y_{n+2} + h\left( \frac{23}{12} f(t_{n+2}, y_{n+2}) - \frac43 f(t_{n+1}, y_{n+1}) + \frac{5}{12}f(t_n, y_n)\right)
$$

Where $h$ is the difference between each timestep $t_i$.  I'm not sure what they want for the derivation, but in the end of the day, you should have:

$$
\begin{align}
y_{n+3} &= y_{n+2}  \\ 
+& h\frac{23}{12} (0.5y_{n+2} - 2.5\sin(t_{n+2})) \\ 
-& h\frac43 (0.5y_{n+1} - 2.5\sin(t_{n+1})) \\ 
+& h\frac{5}{12}(0.5y_{n} - 2.5\sin(t_{n}))
\end{align}
$$

as your recursive definition.  In your terminology, this becomes

$$
\begin{align}
w_{i+1} &= w_{i}  \\ 
+& h\frac{23}{12} (0.5w_{i} - 2.5\sin(t_{i})) \\ 
-& h\frac43 (0.5w_{i-1} - 2.5\sin(t_{i-1})) \\ 
+& h\frac{5}{12}(0.5w_{i-2} - 2.5\sin(t_{i-2}))
\end{align}
$$

As you can see from the definition, this method requires $3$ starting values.  For whatever $h$ you choose, our starting three values are
$$
w_0 = 2\cos(t_0) + \sin(t_0)=2\\
w_1 = 2\cos(t_1) + \sin(t_1)\\
w_2 = 2\cos(t_2) + \sin(t_2)
$$
Where for each $i$: $t_i=i\cdot h$.

Could you code this problem for here? If not, where do you run into difficulty?

---

### The Code:

```
%INITIALIZATION:
h = .01; % This is your timestep interval (step size)
a = 0; % This is your starting point
b = 12; % This is your ending point

t = a:h:b; %an array of all timesteps
L = length(t);
w = zeros(1,L); %the array that will eventually contain AB approximation
for i = 1:3
    w(i) = 2*cos(t(i))+sin(t(i));
end

%ITERATION
for i = 3:(L-1)
    part_1 = h*(23/12)*(0.5*w(i)-2.5*sin(t(i)));
    part_2 = -h*(4/3)*(0.5*w(i-1)-2.5*sin(t(i-1)));
    part_3 = h*(5/12)*(0.5*w(i-2)-2.5*sin(t(i-2)));
    w(i+1) = w(i) + part_1 + part_2 + part_3;
end

%TO PLOT THE FUNCTION, ADD
plot(t,w)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Will try to code from here

Comment: I think you should be fine on your own. If you do get stuck though, add another comment here and I'll try to help.

Comment: I need desperate help with this code. Anyone? I can copy and paste what I know so far...

Comment: clear
% Adams- Moulton Two-Step Method
% initial data
a = input(í Enter a, the initial value of t: í)
b = input(í Enter b, the final value of t: í)
N = input(í Enter number of subintervals, N: í)
% step size
h = (b-a)/N
for i=1:N+1, t(i)=a+(i-1)*h; end
% numerical solution w
% starting values
w(1) = 1;
w(2) = t(2) + exp( -t(2) );
% Adams-Moulton s

Comment: How would I vary this for the AB method? Not the AM one

Comment: I'll put some code up in the question

Comment: See if my code works for you